# Django forms how to initialze only not required field instead of passing all required fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True)
    fieldA = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    fieldB = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    fieldC = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    fieldD = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

class Meta:
   model = Student
   fields = '__all__'
```

Based on the above example all fields are taken in UpdateView or CreateView.
If i need to take only required field i can change Meta to

```
class Meta:
   model = Student
   fields = ['name','fieldA',fieldB','fieldC']
```

So my question is how can add only fields that should not pass in the Meta.From above example 'fieldD' is not passed. Is there is any way to say 'fieldD' is not required instead on passing all required fields in Meta.So that the code can be reduced.

Above one is a small example. Consider I have 200 fields and only 1 field that I didnot want to pass so instead of passing 199 required fields in Meta is there is anyway to tell only the 1 field should not pass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Meta.exclude`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#selecting-the-fields-to-use) instead of `Meta.fields` to define only the fields that should not be present on the form

```
class StudentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        exclude = ['fieldD']
```